# SSRS Report Timeout From Site - From Report Builder Works Fine

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I'm working on SSRS report. It works fine when I run it from Report Builder.

*Now, when I run the same report from my site, which uses Report viewer to show the report, timeout issue occurs. So I have observed that it times out after 90 seconds. Can anyone please help me what should I do in this case?*

*- I've set **Do not timeout report** from Site Settings*

[image]

*- I've also set Time in Report Dataset properties.*

[image]

- *I also tried, Processing Options.*

[image]

Comment: It's just a mere guess, but... is the connection between your site and the report server set up right?

Comment: Chances are the report builder is caching data locally, making it seem like it is working there. Do you get the same timeout, or long running query, when you refresh the data in report builder?

Comment: I'm getting same timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was issue with `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager`

I needed to add AsyncPostBackTimeout="56000" to `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager`.

***Before***

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"/>
```

***After***

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" AsyncPostBackTimeout="56000"/>
```

*Now it works fine.*

Answer (score 0):

For starters, in your data set properties, I would set the time out property for all data sets to 0. This should mean that they do not time out. This may not be a practical decision for all reports all the time but if you're having timeout issues, that's a good place to start.

Do you just have one dataset? And if so, when you run the query in SQL Server Management Studio, how long does it take to execute?

Comment: thanks for answer. It was having issue `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager`. I have answered to my own question so that it can help to others. btw from SSMS it was taking around 3 mins to execute and I had two dataset on same report. But second one was taking less time than first one. again thanks for answer. :)